# Construct a variable that conditionally takes a certain value until another condition is met

Tags: r, database, loops, if-statement

I have a panel dataset with data on conflicts for which I want to identify the post-conflict years.

So I constructed a variable myself, which codes a transition from conflict to peace with "3". Whenever the values for a new country begin, I coded that same variable with NA. S

What I want to do now is to create a new binary variable which identifies post-conflict years with a 1 and conflict years and never conflict with 0. For that I would have to assign every year, following a 3 in the transition variable with a 1 until there is an NA in the same column. As follows:

```
Country       Year   transition    post-conflict
Afghanistan   1994   0  0
Afghanistan   1995   0  0
Afghanistan   1996   3  1
Afghanistan   1997   2  1
Afghanistan   1998   2  1
Albania       1994   NA 0
Albania       1994   2  0
```

How could I go about this?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use `NA` like that. It prevents functions like `which`, `sum`, and `cumsum` from working as you may want them to. You likely don't need to mark the first row of a new country anyway, since most R functions you would use for your analysis can group by `Country` without needing a special marker showing where each group starts.

Below I change `NA` to something different, and make `transition` a factor. Then you can use `cumsum` to create your new column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # assuming your data is called df

# fix transition column
df[is.na(transition), transition := 90]
df[, transition := as.factor(transition)]

# create post_conflict column
df[, post_conflict := cumsum(transition == 3), by = Country]

#        Country Year transition post_conflict
# 1: Afghanistan 1994          0             0
# 2: Afghanistan 1995          0             0
# 3: Afghanistan 1996          3             1
# 4: Afghanistan 1997          2             1
# 5: Afghanistan 1998          2             1
# 6:     Albania 1994         90             0
# 7:     Albania 1994          2             0
```

Comment: Aww thanks a lot man 
You saved me from despair (and I guess severe hair loss :) )